# Remove e-mail string from the beginning of each row in a file

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface, cut

I have a file with the following format

```
email1@email.com some string with no set width
email2@email.com another string
email3@email.com yet another string!!
areallylongemail@email.com shortstring
```

What I want to do is run a bash command that will get this file and remove the email+space from the beginning of EACH row and output that to another file. The output file should be

```
some string with no set width
another string
yet another string!!
shortstring
```

So far I have `sed 's/^\S+\s//' test_input.txt > test_output.txt` but does not seem to work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[^[:blank:]@]\+@[^[:blank:]]\+[[:blank:]]*//' file > file.out
some string with no set width
another string
yet another string!!
shortstring
```

gnu sed will work with this:

```
sed 's/^[^\s@]\+@\S\+\s*//' file > file.out
```

Comment: `$ sed 's/^[^\s@]\+@\S\+\s*//' test_input.txt
email1@email.com some string with no set width
email2@email.com another string
email3@email.com yet another string!!
areallylongemail@email.com shortstring`

not working for some reason

Comment: Can one line have more than one email address also? It worked with the data you provided, if you edit the question with the data for which it didn't work I can look into that.

Comment: No only one e-mail address, and I used the same input as this question above.

Comment: I think you will need 's/regex1/regex2/g' since you want to replace all occurrences of emails in the file. you can also use -i flag to do it in place.

Comment: @barrigaj: [Check this working demo with same sed command](http://ideone.com/2E7uX9)

Comment: Sorry, what is [[:blank:]]. It seems the first option is working but not the second

Comment: `[[:blank:]]` is POSIX class that matches a space or tab. 2nd command is gnu-sed specific so your sed may be little older.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only a single space separating the email address from the rest of the line, then you could use the `cut` command, tell it to use the space as a field delimiter, and have it output all fields starting with the second field.

```
cut -d' ' -f2- < file > file.out
```